# Installing new lyx layout: where are my layout files?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I'm hoping to find an easy solution to this problem.

I want to install the American Economic Association document class and use it in Lyx.  I have inserted the class file into the right latex directory and run texhash.  Next I created a simple layout file, played it in the layout folder, and reconfigured Lyx.  Now, American Economic Association (AEA) appears in my dropdown menu as a document class option in class under the articles heading, but when I try to use the file, it tells me that there is a problem with the layout file.

I suspect that I have no found the correct layout folder. The layout folder I'm using is empty except for the file I added.  Is this normal?  I can't find, for example, the article.layout file.  I should say that Lyx appears to be working normally otherwise.  I have no problem compiling normal files.

I'm on a Macbook Pro running OSX Yosemite.  The directory I have been using for layout files is /Users/amandaggregg/Library/Application Support/LyX-2.1/layouts, which Lyx preferences indicate should be the right folder.

I know about http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/lyx/surefire_layout.htm, but it looks complicated and time-consuming.  Hoping to find an easier solution.

Looking forward to your responses

Comment: If you go to File > New From Template, and open AEA.lyx, can you compile it? LyX comes with an AEA layout file. You could search for ".layout" files on your computer: `locate ".layout"`. LyX has two layout directories, one in the installation directory (in lib/layout) and one in your user directory.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I deleted the layout file I made, reconfigured Lyx, and used File > New From Template.  Works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: For posterity, I located the layout files in /Applications/LyX.app/Contents/Resources/layouts/ using the locate ".layout" command as you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Layout Folders**

There are generally two folders, where LyX searches for `.layout` files: A system-wide folder (for all users, usually one needs root privileges to alter this) and a user-specific folder in the users home. It depends on your operating system, where exactly these are located. The directories listed in *Preferences->Paths* are a good starting point.

**Document-Local Layout**

However, in most cases it is easier (and preferable) to store the custom `.layout` file together with the respective LyX-Document (that is, in the same folder as the `.lyx` file). Then select this by clicking the *Local Layout...* button under *Document Settings->Document Class*.

Comment: Which of the 10 paths in the preferences dialog is searched for system layouts?

Comment: @DSJustice: Strangely enough, none. In the preferences you can only configure use-specific paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "Tools > Reconfigure". (I had the same problem and this worked for me.)

Comment: Please, can you complete your little answer, also with the images, more explantions,....?

Answer (score 0):

On Manjaro Linux 21.0.7, with LyX 2.3.6.1-2 installed from the official repositories (`extra/lyx`), the paths are configured by default this way:

[image: Preferences view of LyX, showing Working Directory set to $HOME]

with "Working directory" set to `$HOME`. In `$HOME`, I have a `.lyx` folder, which has a `layouts` folder where you can put the `.layout` file. It looks like this:

```
❯ tree -L 2 -l .lyx
.lyx
├── bbxFiles.lst
├── bibFiles.lst
├── bind
├── bstFiles.lst
├── cache
│   ├── 1917147396-png
│   └── index
├── cbxFiles.lst
├── clipart
├── clsFiles.lst
├── configure.log
├── doc
├── examples
├── images
├── kbd
├── layouts
│   └── exam.layout
├── lyxciteengines.lst
├── lyxmodules.lst
├── lyxrc.defaults
├── packages.lst
├── scripts
├── session
├── styFiles.lst
├── templates
├── textclass.lst
├── ui
└── xtemplates.lst
```

You can see the `exam.layout` file I was trying to install. After placing it in the `layouts` folder, do Tools > Reconfigure inside LyX and then restart LyX, and it should work.